# x86 Irvine32: Assembly language - Get last array

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, irvine32

I'm trying to figure out this program. Just want to know if I'm on point with the program. How do I correct this program? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

"Write an assembly language program that has an array of words. The program loads the last element of the array into an appropriately sized register and prints it. (Do not hardcode the index of the last element.)"

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc    
.data
  val1 word 1,2,3,4,5,6
  val2 = ($-val1)/2  ; This is hardcoding
.code
main PROC        
  mov ax, 0
  mov ax, val1[val2]

  Call WriteDec
  Call DumpRegs
 exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: When you say "correct", what do you mean? The hardcoding comment?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `val2 = ($-val1)/2`, one option would be to choose some terminating character for the array, for example, `'$'`, and loop until it's found:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc    
.data
  val1 word 1,2,3,4,5,6,'$'                ;ARRAY WITH TERMINATING CHARACTER.
  val2 = ($-val1)/2  ; This is hardcoding
.code
main PROC        
  ;mov ax, 0
  ;mov ax, val1[val2]

  mov si, offset val1    ;SI POINTS TO VAL1.
  mov ax, '$'            ;TERMINATING CHARACTER.
repeat:
  cmp [ si ], ax
  je  dollar_found       ;IF [ SI ] == '$'
  add si, 2              ;NEXT WORD IN ARRAY.
  jmp repeat

dollar_found:  
  sub si, 2              ;PREVIOUS WORD.
  mov ax, [ si ]         ;FINAL WORD!

  Call WriteDec
  Call DumpRegs
 exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate part of your answer on a duplicate question.  It's much better to mark the question as a duplicate.  (Which we can now do, since I'm upvoting your bigger answer on the other question).

Comment: @PeterCordes, understood, buddy! Actually, both answers were different, later, I pasted this one at the end of the other. Anyway, the OP doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Ah I see.  I only see one close-vote on the question.  You can vote-to-close this as a duplicate, even though you've answered it.